# Why do greater than and less than symbols match in the following regex?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'm trying to limit the punctuation that a user can enter into a text box and am using this regex:

```
^[\w ,-–\[\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\}/!@#&\`\.'\n\r\f\t""’]*$
```

Why do > and < produce a match?  They are not included in the regex.
NOTE: this is being used in a asp.net regular expression validator.

Edit:  here's the asp.net source:

```
<input runat="server" type="text" id="txt_FName" class="textbox" maxlength="60" />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rfvRegexFName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_FName" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:Subscribe, inputValidationError %>" />
```

In the code behind I add the expression:

```
rfvRegexFName.ValidationExpression = @"^[\w ,-–\[\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\}/!@#&\`\.'\n\r\f\t""’]*$";
```

Comment: Give an example of something that you want to match.

Comment: I'm curious how you're doing the match. If you're using the RegEx pattern to find matches in the entire input from the text box, then I don't think you want the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of string characters, and you would want a `+` instead of the `*` at the end. That way it'd match any illegal punctuation in the string. As of right now, it seems like it'd only match if the text box input consisted of all bad punctuation and nothing else.

Comment: so, it would be ""’]+$ at the end?

Comment: Well, that's not quite what I mean. Can you post the line of code where you use this RegEx? That'd help me explain what I mean and whether you need to change it in the first place.

Comment: Added the line of code as requested

Comment: I just realized I've been thinking about this backwards. Ignore what I said here! How you have it right now is exactly how you need it. See my comments to @Joel on @Ben Hocking's answer for clarification on why I was thinking you wouldn't want the start and end characters.

Comment: No problem. Sorry about the confusion. Now, the only thing I would say now is that your current pattern will match an empty string. If you want to make sure that something is entered in the text box, then you would want to change that asterisk at the end to a plus. So: `]+$` at the very end. Make sense? That way, the input will only be valid if it contains no bad characters and if it's not empty. If you don't care if it's empty, then it's fine how it is.

Comment: It does make sense, but i have a required field validator with a separate error message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why do > and < produce a match?

Probably because the `-` (hyphen) in `,-–` matches the character range [`,` to `–`]. Either escape the hyphen: `,\-–` or place the hyphen at the very start or end of the class which causes it to match the literal `-` instead.

Also note that you need not escape the `$`, `.`, `|`, `?`, `*`, `+`, `(`, `)`, `{` and `}` inside a character class

Comment: Removing everything but `^[ -–]*$` results in a match; `^[ \-–]*$` does not.

Comment: +1 Good catch. I read right past it. Ironically, its one of the few things that really need to be escaped here.

Comment: To be honest, I'm kind of a regex noob, I started with ^[\w]*$ and expanded from there.

Comment: It is a good practice to put the - as the last character in a character group to prevent it from creating a range

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: After seeing the other answers, it looks like there might have been a few things going on here. The main problem was the unescaped dash, though. For future reference of anyone reading this Q/A thread, see Bart Kiers' answer.**

You don't want to escape the period. When it's inside the brackets, it matches a regular period by default, not any character like it does normally. I'm not positive, but that might be making it act as a special character again, therefore matching anything.

Try this:

```
^[\w ,-–\[\\\^\$.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\}/!@#&\`'\n\r\f\t""’]*$
```

Comment: I escaped the two different dashes near the front and that seemed to have done the trick.  I'll accept your as you were kind enough to answer.  Here's the completed regex:
^[\w ,\-\–\[\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\}/!@#&\`\.'\n\r\f\t""’]*$

Comment: Sorry, I will accept your answer in 6 minutes, when the system lets me.

Comment: I appreciate it, but Bart Kiers answered with the escaped dash, so he's probably more deserving of having his answer accepted. :)

Comment: Saw it JUST after the refresh. Noted and changed.

Comment: Also, if you feel this is a silly way to restrict malicious user input, please let me know.

Comment: @Dave - Using regular expressions isn't a silly way to do this, but just restricting special characters isn't always enough.  If the user is submitting code there may be ways to generate the character with a sequence you didn't think of.  Also, some unicode characters look like and map to ASCII characters you'd want to disallow, but if the regex engine you're using supports UTF8 then you'd miss it because it isn't converted to ASCII before checking the text.  I don't have an incredible solution for that off the top of my head.

Comment: @Brian Vandenberg - Thanks, I don't particularly like this solution but there never is a sure fire way to prevent bad user input.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last * to a +. You're matching zero or more instances, which always guarantees a match.

Edit to add: Are all of those characters regular ASCII? It looks like you might be using an em-dash or something, which might be related to your problem.

Comment: He's using the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of string characters, though.

Comment: However, it's a good point, and I'm not sure why he's using the start and end characters. Without them, he'd definitely want a plus (`+`) instead.

Comment: @Compeek Without the start and end characters, his regex can match something in the middle of the string, but have stuff outside that he considers illegal. E.g. "(a)" would match because of the "a" in the middle.

Comment: I'm trying to prevent input of malicious script code.  I'm HTML encoding the value in the DB (it's not being displayed back on a webpage).
I want to stick with ascii because I'm afraid if I let in unicode values, I'll let in some fancy shmancy new way of adding script tags to my input that I hadn't thought of.

Comment: @Joel, I might be misunderstanding you, but let me explain what I mean. I don't know ASP.NET, but this is what I'd do in PHP: `preg_match('/[bad characters in here]+/', $input, $matches);`. (By the way, the slashes mark the ends of the pattern.) That would fill the $matches array with any bad characters found in the input. So if there are no matches, then I know there are no bad characters. If I did `'^[bad characters in here]*$'` instead, I would **only** get a match if the _entire_ input string contained nothing but bad characters, or if the string was empty. Do you get what I'm saying?

Comment: Ohhhh, wait. Nevermind. Ignore everything I said before. I've been mistakenly thinking he's matching bad characters. He's matching all _allowed_ characters. So yes, definitely needs the start and end characters. My mistake!